# Providing internet access to Beaglebone black through USB host

Tags: beagleboneblack, beagleboard

Currently I am using beaglebone black device for one of my IOT Projects. The application written over it reads data through the BACnet IP based BMS system  (using ethernet port of beaglebone) and sends to the remote cloud using the internet access. It sends data to the remote cloud using Skywire LTE cape and modem. For some reasons, i need to remove the skywire cape. The option i am left with for providing internet access to the beaglebone is through the usb host port. I am using (ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM) usb dongle device for this. when it is connected to the beaglebone usb host port, it is getting detected. the result of the lsusb commands is following

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 19d2:1557 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

what should be the next step going forward such that the ethernet port should function normally and usb host port is used to access the internet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The BBB-s USB port won't provide enough current for GSM modems. You need a USB hub with external power supply or the modem will just reboot when it tries to bring up the radio. Then follow standard dial-up instructions for either pppd or ofono/connman (if your modem is supported).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tarmo. I needed to test it for demo purose. Could you please guide on how to get it running using either the ppd or connman method that you just suggested. Some link or user guide too will do. The 4G USB dongle modem i am talking about gets detected as eth6 port in my linux pc. Want to make sure it will rung along with ethernet port too in BBB. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, the newer ones create a virtual Ethernet device and it would probably be easier to use this instead of trying to establish dial-up. I don't know which software manages networks on BB these days. It used to be connman, which isn't easy to use. Maybe they've switched to NetworkManager. Have a look at the [Ubuntu documentation](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/networkmanager/configure-cellular-connections) - with a bit of luck you should be able to use it after installing NetworkManager and ModemManager (`sudo apt update && sudo apt install network-manager modemmanager`).